# Shop light wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, light-fixture, light

I am hoping to put two 4ft flourescent lights in my garage where it only had a single light bulb before. I have never done anything electrical so even the simplest job is all new to me. 
My question is, do I need to ground each light fixture with the bare wire? Or do I connect the hot, neutral and ground wires to each light then ground only the second/last light with the bare wire?
I have searched this & other sites, I can't find the answer to this simple question. Any help would be great.

Comment: if there is a ground wire in the existing light junction box, then just run the three wires to the first fixture and then to the second fixture

Comment: Check out the LED fixtures before you commit to fluorescent.

Comment: Unfortunately they keep making the light quality better and better on actual fluorescent.  I'm staying with them, plus can't beat the price.

Comment: I do appreciate the responses but I have flourescent. I'm not asking which is better, I'm sure led is fine but the wiring is what I know absolutely nothing about.

Comment: @Harper they keep making better LED too, a year ago I wouldn't have thought I would ever be happy with fluorescent replacements.

Comment: Does anyone have an answer to the question that I actually asked?

Comment: Where in the world are you?  Specifics may differ by country.

Comment: Ok, I live in Nevada. I didn't know that grounding lamps had different codes for different areas. So that is something I can go look up myself but I just can't find anything about whether or not it is necessary to ground each lamp or only the last one in line.

Comment: @user81496 What do you mean by "connect the hot, neutral and ground wires to each light then ground only the second/last light with the bare wire". By definition, hooking up the ground wire is grounding the fixture. Why should you need another bare wire that only goes to one fixture?

Comment: Well as I said, I have no knowledge of this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You run hot, neutral and ground to each of the lights.

The bare wire and the ground are one and the same.

One thing I often do is fit receptacles on the ceiling (inside junction boxes of course) and use fluorescent lights which plug in via a cord - many fluorescents come with a 6 inch (150mm) cord, some with a 6' (2m) or longer cord.  Sometimes one well placed receptacle can serve two fluorescent lights.

I'm not a fan yet, but many people like LED "fluorescent replacements".  New real fluorescents are neck and neck for quality IMO.